# How to solve this issue: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework-6

Can anyone help me to fix this issue of cast? Here is my code. When i use a breakpoint at the start of using(TaxiPlannerEntities), it does not step in the foreach and it goes directly to the catch exception e and show me this error.

```
 public class BookingController : Controller
    {
        /*[HttpPost]*/
       // [Route("InsertBooking")]
        public string Book(int employee_ID , List<DateTime> datebooked)
        {

            using (TaxiPlannerEntities contextx = new TaxiPlannerEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    //Create new booking
                    var booking1 = new booking();
                    booking1.uid = employee_ID;

                    List<DateTime> y = new List<DateTime>();
                    y.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(datebooked));

                   /* y.Add(DateTime.Now);
                    y.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
                    y.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
                    y.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3));*/
                   /* y.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(datebooked));*/


                    foreach (DateTime x in y)
                    {

                        var db1 = new booking_date
                        {
                            bookingDate = x
                        };
                        db1.status = "pending";
                        booking1.booking_date.Add(db1);

                    }

                    contextx.bookings.Add(booking1);
                    contextx.SaveChanges();

                    return "success";
                }

                catch (Exception e)

                {
               //     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
                    return e.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace); inside of catch clause to find which line causes exception.

Comment: You're trying to convert, `Convert.ToDateTime(datebooked)`, an entire `List<DateTime>`, adding a single element, the result of the conversion, to another `List<DateTime>`. What is this conversion supposed to achieve?

Comment: @Arphile I've tried this but it's not showing me the line causes exception

Comment: Is there any data in y. How much is the data count in y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `datebooked` variable is already a `List<DateTime>`. Don't try to use `Convert.ToDateTime` on it and then add the result to `y` (It won't work; you cannot concert a list of dates to a single date)

Remove any mention of `y` from your code and use `datebooked` in its place instead:

```
foreach(DateTime x in datebooked)
```

And so on..

If you only meant to use one of the dates in the `datebooked` List (it's name is not a plural which implies you meant for it to be a single date?) then just index the list like an array and take eg the first date, or change the method signature so it takes a single date rather than a list of dates

---

This line also looks a bit odd:

```
booking1.booking_date.Add(db1);
```

If its the case that you have a collection of `booking_date` objects it would make the code more readable to call the collection `BookingDates` (plural)

You should always try to match the plural-ness of your variable names to the types of objects on your code; collections should be plurals